# How to sum maps based on other values

Tags: groovy

I have a map that looks like:

```
myMap = [
  [value1: "ABD123", value2: "Robert", value3: 1, value4: "7"],
  [value1: "ABD123", value2: "Robert", value3: 4, value4: "7"],
  [value1: "ABD13a23", value2: "Rob2ert", value3: 1, value4: "7"]
]
```

I'd like to sum `value3` if the other 3 values are the same.

The output of this would be:

```
myMap = [
  [value1: "ABD123", value2: "Robert", value3: 5, value4: "7"],
  [value1: "ABD13a23", value2: "Rob2ert", value3: 1, value4: "7"]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

My way:

```
def myMap = [
  [value1: "ABD123", value2: "Robert", value3: 1, value4: "7"],
  [value1: "ABD123", value2: "Robert", value3: 4, value4: "7"],
  [value1: "ABD13a23", value2: "Rob2ert", value3: 1, value4: "7"]
]

def summed = myMap.groupBy{ it.value1 }.collect{ k, v -> v.first() + [ value3:v*.value3.sum() ] }

assert summed == [
  [
    "value1": "ABD123",
    "value2": "Robert",
    "value3": 5,
    "value4": "7"
  ],
  [
    "value1": "ABD13a23",
    "value2": "Rob2ert",
    "value3": 1,
    "value4": "7"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some prefer the `inject` method, for example:

```
def myMap = [
        [value1: "Welcome to stackoverflow!", value2: "Now you have 998 ways how to skin a cat left!", value3: 1, value4: "Friday night again!"],
        [value1: "Welcome to stackoverflow!", value2: "Now you have 998 ways how to skin a cat left!", value3: 4, value4: "Friday night again!"],
        [value1: "You really should show what you tried and the issue you're having", value2: "Now you have 997 ways how to skin a cat left!", value3: 1, value4: "Friday night again!"]
]
def result = myMap.inject([:].withDefault {0}) { acc, map ->
    def map2 = map.clone()
    map2.value3 = 0
    acc[map2] += map.value3
    acc
}.collect { k, v -> k.value3 = v; k }
```